# stuck in an infinite loop, julia code

Tags: r, julia

I tried translating my R code to Julia, but my perceptron function in the julia code is in an infinite loop and I cannot find my mistake.

what the code does:
1. make 100 random data points in [-1,1]^2
2. generate 2 random points in [-1,1], the linear line f between them serves as
a linear separator
3. classify the 100 points in 2 classes (-1 and 1) below and above f, ylist is a list of -1 and 1s depending on the class.
4. build a hypothesis for f with the perception algorithm

R Code:

```
#library(MASS)
#library(ggplot2)
n <- 100
datam <- matrix(c(rep(1,n), 2*runif(n)-1, 2*runif(n)-1), n)
a <- 2*runif(2)-1
b <- 2*runif(2)-1
f <- lm(a ~ b)
fff <- coef(f)
test <- c(1, fff[1], fff[2])
ylist <- sign(datam %*% test)

perceptron = function(datam, ylist) {
w <- c(1,0,0)
made.mistake = TRUE 
while (made.mistake) {
made.mistake=FALSE 
for (i in 1:n) {
  if (ylist[i] != sign(t(w) %*% datam[i,])) {
    w <- w + ylist[i]*datam[i,]
    made.mistake=TRUE 
  }
}
}
return(w=w)
}

perceptron(datam,ylist)
```

julia code:

```
n = 100

fp = [2*rand(2)-1 for i = 1:2 ]

A = [ones(n,1) c=2*rand(n)-1 d=2*rand(n)-1]  

m = (fp[2][2]-fp[1][2])/(fp[2][1]-fp[1][1])

b = fp[2][2]-m*fp[2][1]

funkt = [1 m b]

ylist = sign(A*funkt') 

w = A\ylist


function perceptron(data, y)
v = [1 0 0]
mistake = true
while mistake
    mistake = false
    for i = 1:n
        if y[i] != sign(v*data[i,:]')
            v = v + y[i]*data[i,:]
            mistake = true
        end
    end
end
return v
end

perceptron(A,ylist)
```

I'm always open for other code improvements

Comment: Pretty obvious that your `y` or `v` assignment does something different in Julia than in R.  Run just the inner loop on a subset of `y` (in both languages) and see what the actual values are you generate.

Comment: I think I found the problem, sign(v*data[i,:]') yields an Integer, while y[i] is a float.

Comment: found a solution: change y[i] to y[i,:] in the for loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To give a more complete description of the issues behind the solution you found on your own, Julia treats a scalar differently from an array with one element:

```
julia> 5 == [5]
false
```

So a scalar, `y[i]`, will never test as being equal to a matrix, `v*data[i,:]'`.

Your solution, to write `y[i,:]`, ensures that both the left and right sides are matrices. An alternative is to ensure that both sides are scalars, which you could do by extracting the first element of the RHS, e.g., `sign((v*data[i,:]')[1])`.

However, there are somewhat better ways to do this (which only matter if you want better performance). A few tips:

- In general, if you want a 1-dimensional object, you should use commas rather than spaces:

  ```
  funkt = [1,m,b]  # Gives a 1-d array, [1 m b] gives a 2-d array
  ylist = sign(A*funkt)
  ```
- Because of the way memory is stored, it's much more efficient to extract columns than rows, so you might consider defining `A` as the transpose of what you have here.
- The `dot` function takes two vectors and computes their dot product, which is a scalar.

Comment: thanks, I hope to get a better understanding of julia soon. It's a great language. I made this example to test the speed against the same thing in R and the results are swesome.